# SSL When using (A) Record to point domain

Tags: ssl-certificate, dns-zone

Im not even sure this can be done but I will ask. Its been many years since i've done this and I have forgotten most things.

(1) Domain is at my hosting provider
(2) We have a platform (website) on another server (Not hosted by us)
Domain is pointed using (A) Record to the IP address of remote platform

### Is there anyway we can get SSL or must that be done server side where the platform is hosted?

We don't want to point our nameservers to them because they have a tendency to mess things up. I cant find a way to redirect the domain with masking in cPanel however that would be ideal.
domain: mygrubrunner.com --> mygrubrunner.rdslogic.com

Someone said I can use cname? ¯_(ツ)_/¯ (im lost)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by your question but I'll take a stab at it.

1. Purchase an SSL certificate for the name you want to "protect". You'll need to prove ownership of the domain name that the certificate "protects" (Domain Control Validation). Typically you will do this via email or by creating a DNS record in your DNS zone.
2. Once the certificate has been issued you'd typically download it and install it on your server. In this case you'll send it to the web hosting company to install on your website.

None of this requires that you move your DNS, do any masking, redirection, etc.

Answer (score 0):

SSL depends on a certificate set that is used to identify and encrypt the data coming off the server (in this case I assume a web server). This certificate set, because it is being used by the server in your host, must be on the host that is doing the serving. (In theory it could be on a separate machine that is accessible to your server, but there are significant security risks and so I don't know a server that actually allows that.) DNS does not enter into the picture, unless you choose to have a different name for your SSL host - and why would you?

The process of getting these certificates can be dependent on DNS, if for instance you use Certbot to get a free LetsEncrypt certificate - one of the techniques for validating your domain is to create a specifically named TXT record in your DNS. But where your DNS is hosted makes little difference - almost all of the certificate operations pretty well have to be on your server.

Redirecting the domain is a completely different question, and if cPanel is involved, does not belong in this part of StackExchange; cPanel completely messes up hosting and has its own set of experts elsewhere.